# Parsing "dd MMMM, yyyy" using DateTime.TryParseExact

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, tryparse

I'm working with [`TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-8.0#system-datetime-tryparseexact(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles-system-datetime@)) but it's throwing an error.
What could be the issue? Thanks

```
DateTime result;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact("31 December, 2023", ["'dd MMMM, yyyy'"],
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    // Success
}
else 
{
    // Failure
}
```

I've tried escaping the date format as "dd MMMM',' yyyy" and using `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` but there's no effect.

Comment: why the ' in the format?

Comment: so instead of `"'dd MMMM, yyyy'"` it should be `"dd MMMM, yyyy"`

Comment: as you can see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PLY8Q7

Answer (score 3):

When you see the `Exact` in `TryParseExact()`, **it means it**; the method is _super strict_ about the input _exactly matching_ the specified format.~~

In this case, the single quotes in this string are part of the expected format:

```
'dd MMMM, yyyy'
```

To match this format, the date would need to look like this:

```
'31 December, 2023'
```


You probably want to use this format string instead:

```
dd MMMM, yyyy
```

---

Finally, I know it's probably just an example, but if you really have a constant value you're also generally better off using the `DateTime` constructor, like this:

```
DateTime result = new(2023, 12, 31);
```

or this, if you're not yet comfortable with the newer syntax:

```
var result = new DateTime(2023, 12, 31);
```

Comment: No, it's worse than that: to match the format, the string would have to be exactly `dd MMMM, yyyy` (e.g. `string text = "dd MMMM, yyyy";`) ... the apostrophes mean that everything between them is quoted literally, not interpreted as format specifiers...

Comment: @JonSkeet Ooh, good catch (as usual) :)